# Solving a simple system of differential equations

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-methods, differential-equations

How would I numerically solve for the following simple system of differential equations using **Octave**?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Note:

- I use the qualifier "simple" as, from my understanding, the system is
  first order and is not coupled.
- I have tried every
  method and script online to try solve    this including [here](http://web.mit.edu/voigtlab/BP205/Notes/BP205_Matlab_slides.pdf),
  [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) and [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/Octave/OctaveODE-EG.html). In all options, I    either get a hanging,
  non-responsive Octave, a prompt stating    "repeated convergence
  failures", an error with recommendation that    I manually adjust
  the initial and maximum step size (which I did try    and do, to no
  avail), or something that initially seems like a solution on account of no errors but plotting the solution shows a blank graph
- Where Octave provided for equivalent Matlab routines, I tried the various routines `ode45`, `ode23`, `ode113`, `ode15s`, `ode23s`, `ode23t`, `ode23tb`, `ode15i` and of course, Octaves own `lsode` command, all giving the same errors described above.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first replicate the vanilla solution

```
% z = [x,y]
f = @(t,z) [ z(1).^2+t; z(1).*z(2)-2 ];
z0 = [ 2; 1];

[ T, Z ] = ode45(f, [0, 10], z0);

plot(T,Z); legend(["x";"y"]);
```

The integrator fails as reported with the warning

> warning:  Solving was not successful.  The iterative integration loop exited at time `t = 0.494898` before the endpoint at `tend = 10.000000` was reached.  This may happen if the stepsize becomes too small.  Try to reduce the value of `'InitialStep'` and/or `'MaxStep'` with the command `'odeset'`.

Repeating the integration up to shortly before the critical time

```
opt = odeset('MaxStep',0.01);
[ T, Z ] = ode45(f, [0, 0.49], z0, opt);
clf; plot(T,Z); legend(["x";"y"]);
```

results in the graph

[image: plot of the solution]

where one can see that the quadratic term in the first equation leads to run-away growth. For some reason the solver does only recognize the ever reducing step size, but not the run-away values of the solution.

Indeed the first is a Riccati equation which are known to have poles at finite times. Using the typical parametrization `x(t)=-u'(t)/u(t)` has by the product/quotient rule the derivative

```
x' = -u''(t)/u(t) - u'(t)* (-u'(t)/u(t)^2) = -u''(t)/u(t) + x(t)^2
```

which then results in the ODE for `u`

```
u''(t)+t*u(t)=0, u(0)=-1, u'(0)=x(0)=2,
```

which is an Airy equation with the oscillating branch for `t>0`. The first root of `u` is a pole for `x`, there is no way to extend the solution beyond this point.

```
g=@(t,u) [u(2); -t.*u(1)]
u0 = [ 1; -2];

function [val,term, dir] = event(t,u)
   val = u(1);
   term = 0;
   dir = 0;
end
opt = odeset('MaxStep',0.1, 'Events', @(t,u) event(t,u));
[T,U,Te,Ue,Ie] = ode45(g,[0,4],u0,opt);
disp(Te)
clf; plot(T,U); legend(["u";"u'"]);
```

which lists the zeros of `u` as `0.4949319379979706, 2.886092605590324`, again confirming the reason for the warning, and gives the plot

[image]

Comment: I lost you when you began to parametrize the solution (due to my own lack of mathematical understanding), but if I understand the essence of your answer, there is essentially a discontinuity which we have to work around. In that case, am I understanding you correct that there is a solution after point 0.4949. So for example, there is a value at x(1) and y(1)?

Comment: No, the solution ends at the singularity, there is no continuation that would make sense. Of course $u$ exists everywhere and so the fraction $-u'/u$ exists on both sides of the pole, but the two segments are not connected, there is no infinitesimal step from left of the singularity to right of the singularity.